# Slow down a calculation in iOS.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Not sure if this is possible, or recommended, however, I have an iPhone application which performs calculations based on my users Age, Height and Weight.  When I tap my calculate button, the resultant output is immediate in that the calc is performed and my UILabel is populated instantaneously.

Is it possible to slow this down and give a 'calculating' on view alert then populate the label?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've heard someone complain about code being too performant.

Comment: It isn't a complaint, more of a wandering of the imagination. I personally like the look and experience of an on screen prompt.  Just wondered if it was possible

Comment: Why give them the answer right away when you can watch a progress bar for five seconds?  It might cause some people to discard their phones: "Geez, it can't even do a simple calculation like BMI!"

Comment: I am yet to discard any device I own that tells me it is in progress of doing something and engages me.  If it sits better with you, treat the question as one of theory and wonder as opposed to actual real world implementation. :)

Comment: Depends on what it's doing.  I'm sure that you can add a Thread.sleep and a progress bar in your theory world.

Comment: Some people just like to learn things, or are intrigued by things, bizarre concept I know to you experienced guys. Thanks for the input though, take it easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a simple NSTimer that gets fired and then use a UIActivityIndicatorView (for example) to show the "loading/calculating" progress inside a view (or even put it inside a UIAlertView) in your app, and then once the timer is complete, uncover the calculated label.

Hope this helps :)

--

Edit; added sample code

```
spinnerAlertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"My App Name", @"") message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease]; // member
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)]; // member
spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[spinnerAlertView addSubview: spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[spinnerAlertView show];
```

Then when the calculation is complete, remember to do this:

```
[spinnerAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];
```

You could tell it to stop animating and hide it from the main view, but this way we just remove it as if though the user dismissed it... much easier.

Answer (score 2):

When your button is clicked, display your loading alert and do this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(calculate) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

- (void)calculate {
//do your calulation and update the result label
}
```

Comment: Ok, that looks like it would have the required effect thank you